# Expected unqualified-id before numeric constant error

Tags: c++, qt, enums, typedef

I have an enum structure like this. I am getting the above error on this enum structure. Me not understanding why this error coming

```
typedef enum
{
a=-3,b=-2,c=-1,d=0,e=1,f=2,

}Variable;
```

Comment: You've forgotten to tag the question with the language you're using. This syntax is valid in some languages, and invalid in many more. This is also missing the context containing this declaration, which may further influence its validity; try creating a [mre].

Comment: Don't use `c++` like `c`. There is no need for `typedef` here.

Comment: Also the program [works](https://godbolt.org/z/48W1WMqhj).

Comment: This is valid C++ code. Your error may be caused somewhere else. Most probably a `#define c XXX`.

Comment: If i dont use typedef , it shows variable does not name type. Above thing valid inC++

Comment: I havent declare it anywhere

Comment: I think the error is caused by code that is not in the question